# Exporting QGIS clipped file to Civil 3D

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have been trying to solve the problem to get a small portion of a larger GIS map into my AutoCAD Civil 3D for a site plan. I currently obtained a large map from the county as a .gdb file and I have successfully imported it.

I just however want a small portion and when I import into Civil 3D I want it to have elevation references which it currently has in the attribute table. I am currently trying to use GRASS plug in to accomplish this.

The steps I have taken so far have been:

1. Made a new shapefile layer
2. performed a toggle edit and made a polygon around the area
3. used processioning tools to make a clip of the area that I want the elevations to show.

I am left with the portion I want however in GRASS it cannot find the layer (clipped layer) to take the elevations off when I use the 3D command.

Can anyone suggest how to associate the elevations with my vector layer or give me an easier suggestion on how to import the data I need into Civil 3D with the elevations given in the contours?